# cordovaCapture captureImage not reading options

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using ionic with the `cordovaCapture` module.

But it doesn't read the options I pass through as a variable:

```
var options = {
    limit: 1,
    quality: 100,
    targetWidth: 1280,
    targetHeight: 1280,
    correctOrientation: true,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};
$cordovaCapture.captureImage(options).then(function (imageData) {
    var imgData = imageData[0].fullPath;
    // here I upload them to remote Server

}, function (error) {
    alert('error');
});
```

The image taken isn't corrected his Orientation, doesnt have the width or height to max 1280px and it's always saved to photoAlbum.. Whats the correct way to set the options?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [$cordovaCapture](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/capture/) or [$cordovaCamera](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/)?

The first one has a really limited set of options; check: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture

The second one is more complete; check:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#module_camera.CameraOptions

but the API to capture is:

```
var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
    }, function(err) {
      // error
    });
```